# Values do not carry forward on applying filter in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am filtering the values on my .xhtml page using `filterBy` method in PrimeFaces. However, on applying filter the values do not carry forward.

The code for my index.xhtml is :

```
<p:column style="text-align:left;white-space:normal;vertical-align:top;width:40%;"
          sortBy="#{certInfo.location.add.addrOnSc}#{certInfo.location.override.NewValue}"
          filterBy="#{certInfo.location.add.addrOnSc}#{certInfo.location.override.NewValue}"
          filterStyle="width:350px"
          filterMatchMode="contains">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{label.add}" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputText value="#{certInfo.location.add.addrOnSc}"
                  rendered="#{!certInfo.location.override.desPremisesChangeInd}"/>

    <h:outputText value="#{certInfo.location.override.NewValue}"
                  rendered="#{certInfo.location.override.desPremisesChangeInd}"
                  style="font-weight:bold;"/>
</p:column>
```

please let me know for any additional information required to solve my question.

Comment: You'll want to clarify what you mean by "carry forward".

Comment: And please check your post. Lots of info missing (no xhtml) and how is this css related?

Comment: Hi DavidS, sorry for the late reply. By "carry forward" I mean that after filtering the values, the values selected on my .xhtml page get cleared out on calling them inside any function call. Is there some generic problem with Primefaces "filterBy" method.